# iOS 13 - UISegmentedControl - How do you change the corner radius of the selectedSegment?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

In regards to iOS 13 updates on UISegmentedControl:

This custom UISegmentedControl class rounds the corners of the segmented control. But it does not round the corners of the selected control (that still has the default corner radius). This makes it look weird, especially when you have a border on the segmented control:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
      override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = 20
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        clipsToBounds = true
     }
}
```

Before you could just do `segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 20` and it would apply to everything but you can't do that anymore.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: Which end are you talking about ? the corner radius seems to be working cann you attach an image on how yours look ?

Answer (score 1):

UISegmentControl doesn't expose internal subviews for any changes. You can use custom segment control that will provide more options for customisation. That's an example from first suggestions results of search on Github: https://github.com/sasojadrovski/SJFluidSegmentedControl

Answer (score 0):

**Create a custom subclass of UISegmentedControl:**

```
    final class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
        private var cornerRadius: CGFloat

        init(cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
            self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    
            guard let selectedSegment = subviews[numberOfSegments] as? UIImageView else {
                return
            }
    
            selectedSegment.image = nil
            selectedSegment.backgroundColor = selectedSegmentTintColor
            selectedSegment.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "SelectionBounds")
            selectedSegment.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius - layer.borderWidth
            selectedSegment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(
                width: selectedSegment.bounds.width,
                height: bounds.height - layer.borderWidth * 2
            ))
        }
    }
```

**Create an instance of SegmentedControl and don't forget to set `selectedSegmentTintColor`**

[Screenshot with segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray5.cgColor and segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cdji.png)